# Can someone please explain this joke?

Tags: jokes

Can someone please explain this joke to me http://bash.org/?5300 ? I don't get it, probably because of low english skills.

[Spoiler used so it doesn't appear on the front page.]

> ```
> <tatclass> YOU ALL SUCK DICK
> <tatclass> er.
> <tatclass> hi.
> <andy\code> A common typo.
> <tatclass> the keys are like right next to each other.
> ```

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it has nothing to do with English. The joke would be exactly the same in every other language. If you don't get it in English, that's not because of English but because you just don't get it. Translate it word for word into your mother tongue, and you'd still not get it. (If you *did* translate it word for word into your mother tongue and *did* get it, then what exactly is your question?)

Comment: By the way, english is the spin you put on the ball in billiards. This site is about English, a Germanic language. Being good at billiards won't really help you with getting bash.org jokes.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I was fixated at what letters I should change in the words "SUCK" or "DICK" to make it funny, translating it word for word doesn't help with this; because in English I expect not to know every word so I was thinking in this direction; in my mother tongue I know (almost) every word which is used in day-to-day situation, so I would be looking for the joke elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "er" is a hesitation, and indicates that Tatclass realises he's made a mistake in relaying the previous line to the community. "hi" is a sheepish greeting (in this case).

You've probably seen television programmes where the presenters are joking amongst themselves and only belatedly realise the cameras are on them.

Andy smooths over the insult by allowing that it's a typo, an easy mistake to make.

Tatclass acknowledges that by saying that the keys he used to type the line in capitals are all next to each other.

The joke is that they are not: Andy's response is actually a form of [irony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony): he's feigning ignorance. Tatclass probably typed his initial line into the wrong window.

> Irony (from Ancient Greek εἰρωνεία (eirōneía), meaning "dissimulation, feigned ignorance"), in its broadest sense, is a rhetorical device, literary technique, or event in which what appears, on the surface, to be the case, differs radically from what is actually the case.

Answer (score 0):

The joke is that the insult was typed "by accident."

"er" is an interjection meaning something like "um", suggesting that a mistake was made, and then "hi" follows, as if that is what the author originally meant.

the other person jokes that the keystrokes for "hi" are right next to the keystrokes for the insult, and thus that the mistake is easy to make (and happens a lot).

;)